# How do I separate a Filepath containing backslashes by replacing only the rootlevel backslash with a tab?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a list of Filepaths, each row includes the filesize and creationdate.

The Filepaths are separated by backslashes, some files in the root folder, others in sub-folders or even in sub-sub-folders.

I am trying to use RegEx in Notepad++ to achieve the desired results.

I merely wish to replace the backslash **immediately after** the root folder with a tab character.

Example:

Current:

```
   289399    13/12/2021    ALLEN Alan - 12.05.2014 - A\File in Root Folder.JPG
    67795    21/12/2021    JONES Jess - 14.09.2010 - B\SUB\File in Level 1 Sub Folder.TXT
   110842    27/05/2020    SMITH Alex - 08.01.2006 - C\SUB\SUB\File in Level 2 Sub-Sub Folder.PDF
```

Desired:

```
   289399    13/12/2021    ALLEN Alan - 12.05.2014 - A <Tab> File in Root Folder.JPG
    67795    21/12/2021    JONES Jess - 14.09.2010 - B <Tab> SUB\File in Level 1 Sub Folder.TXT
   110842    27/05/2020    SMITH Alex - 08.01.2006 - C <Tab> SUB\SUB\File in Level 2 Sub-Sub Folder.PDF
```

Tab separation required at Root Level ***ONLY***

Various methods I have tried using RegEx in Notepad++ fail to achieve the desired result. The tab character almost always replaces the very last backslash character, not the one immediately after the root foldername.

Find:

```
^(.*\t.*\t.*)\\((.*)$|(.*\\.*)$|(.*\\.*\\.*)$)$
```

RegEx:

```
\1\t\2
```

Result:

```
   289399    13/12/2021    ALLEN Alan - 12.05.2014 - A <Tab> File in Root Folder.JPG
    67795    21/12/2021    JONES Jess - 14.09.2010 - B\SUB <Tab> File in Level 1 Sub Folder.TXT
   110842    27/05/2020    SMITH Alex - 08.01.2006 - C\SUB\SUB <Tab> File in Level 2 Sub-Sub Folder.PDF
```

The above RegEx (and variations of this) result in only the final backslash being replaced with a Tab.

I need to replace the first backslash after the Root Foldername only to be replaced, leaving the rest intact.

**Note:**
Some rows will **not** have a letter immediately before the first backslash, e.g.

```
   289399    13/12/2021    ALLEN Alan - 12.05.2014\File in Root Folder.JPG
```

Please can somebody advise of a simple solution for this?

Comment: What should be the result for the last example?

Comment: The result for the anomalous example should be:

   289399 13/12/2021 ALLEN Alan - 12.05.2014 <Tab> File in Root Folder.JPG


Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^[^\\]+\K\\`
- Replace with: `\t`
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # beginning of line
[^\\]+      # 1 or more any character that is not a backslash
\K          # forget all we have seen until this position
\\          # a backslash
```

**Replacement:**

```
\t          # a tabulation
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use the find/replace feature as follows:

**Find what**: `(- [\w.]+)\\`
**Replace with**: `\1\t`
⦿ **Regular Expression**

<kbd>Replace all</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for the above, it works most of the time. However, I've discovered some anomalies in my data, which I have added as a Note in my edited question above describing the scenarios where this doesn't work.

Comment: Updated to also work for such IP addresses.